# Set ng-valid manually in Angular +2

Tags: angular

I have textarea with validation in Angular 4, and when I write something in this textarea I have input that write the same text at same time, the problem is the `ng-invalid` is in input and `ng-valid` in textarea, the text is shown up in input but still `ng-invalid`, how can I make this input understand that something is written on it?

this is my textarea

```
 <textarea class="form-control post-text-input" placeholder="" id="post_box"
     formControlName="post-content" (change)=" checkText(post.postText)" 
     ngModel)]=" post.postText">
 </textarea>
```

this is the input

```
 <input formControlName="post-content" type="text" (change)=" checkText(post.postText)" 
       [(ngModel)]=" post.postText" class="input-text-write emojionearea1" 
       style="padding: 0 25px;"/>
```

**UPDATE**

This is the div that created automatically instead of input:

```
<div class="emojionearea-editor" contenteditable="true" placeholder="" tabindex="0" 
    dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" 
    autocapitalize="off">da
</div>
```

and this is my validation:

```
/* Post Form Validation*/
        this.postForm = fb.group({
            'post-content': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],

        });
```

Comment: i see its correctly done , i dont see any validation applied on in html ...where is validation stuff ?

Comment: @PranayRana check my new update

Comment: check the answer i added based on your update

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: @PranayRana unfortunately no, nothing happened to input, still ng-invalid.

Comment: you dont need ` Validators.minLength(1)` validation as `required` is already there, they both do same thing, suggest you remove `minlength' might resolve your issue

Comment: @PranayRana nothing changed

Comment: is it possible for you to provide code at https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

form the edit its clear that you are using reactive forms for you field `post-content` and if you are using reactive form approach then `[(ngModel)]=" post.postText"` will set value but its not right way to do it .

you have to use `setValue` function to set value on your control. so you code will be like as

html

```
<textarea class="form-control post-text-input" placeholder="" id="post_box"
     formControlName="post-content" (change)=" checkText(post.postText)" 
     ngModel)]=" post.postText">
 </textarea>
<input formControlName="post-content" type="text" 
        (change)="checkText(post.postText)" 
        class="input-text-write emojionearea1" style="padding: 0 25px;"/>
```

ts file

```
    this.postForm = fb.group({
        'post-content': [null, [Validators.required, 
                                  Validators.minLength(1)]],

    });

 //please do change here , right now your both control calling this function
//make appropriate change 
checkText(text) {
   this.postForm.get('post-content').setValue(text);
}
```